# Is it possible to show movement when using the RANK function in MDX?

Tags: mdx, olap, cube

I have written the MDX:

`WITH SET [AgentLeagueTable] AS
    ORDER([Agent].[Agent Hierarchy].[Agent Name].MEMBERS,
          [Measures].[Profit],
           BDESC)
    MEMBER [Measures].[Rank] AS
    RANK([Agent].[Agent Hierarchy].[Agent Name].CURRENTMEMBER,
         [AgentLeagueTable])
  SELECT
    {[Measures].[Agent Rank on Profit], [Measures].[Bkg Profit]} ON 0,
    {[AgentLeagueTable]} ON 1
  FROM
    [TestCube]`

to rank agents by profit and was just curious to know if there was any MDX that could be added, or used to create a new cube measure, that allowed me to show the movement of an agent's position. For example, if an agent dropped 2 places I would like to represent this in a third column as -2 or if they moved up 3 then +3 etc.

Answer (score 0):

So lets say your rankings are updated weekly, So you need another Measure that gives the rank till last week, then you substract the current rank from the last rank. you need to add the following code

```
MEMBER [Measures].[PreviousRank] AS
    RANK(([Agent].[Agent Hierarchy].[Agent Name].CURRENTMEMBER,(use the date dimension till last week)),
         [AgentLeagueTable])

MEMBER [Measures].[RankProgress]
as
[Measures].[Rank]- [Measures].[PreviousRank]
```